# Аналог параллельного цикла из openmp

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++17

Есть ли аналог для `#pragma omp parallel for` из `openmp` в текущем `c++` стандарте?

Comment: Нет. Руками, через `thread` и `async`.

Comment: @Harry так как подобный цикл сделать с помощью `std::thread` и `std::async` ? То что именно такой функции нет - понятно

Comment: Ну руками поделите цикл на нужное количество потоков, создайте и запустите каждый отдельно...

Comment: @Harry вы уверены, что это будет аналогично `openmp`? в смысле скорости работы

Comment: Слушайте, что вы хотите? Вы спросили про аналог - нет, его нет. Все. Задайте вопрос нормально и конкретно, или самостоятельно напишите и проверьте, что будет. Вы понимаете, что в общем случае вам никто ничего определенного сказать не может...

Comment: @Harry мне нужна функция, которая выполнит цикл параллельно без `openmp`

Comment: Еще раз и медленно - пишите сами через `thread` или `async`. Если догадаетесь каждую итерацию засунуть в свой поток - сочувствую. Если нет и ограничитесь количеством ядер/процессоров в задаче, что в итерации нет ожиданий - все равно ничего лучшего у вас нет. Сами смотрите, насколько итерации независимы одна от другой и могут выполняться параллельно...

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, для этого в C++17 появились реализации многих (не всех!) стандартных алгоритмов, Подробнее про это можно посмотреть в описании [политик исполнения](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t).
А вот Вам пример параллельного `for_each`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers(500);
    std::iota(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0);

    std::cout << "Let's roll:\n";
    std::for_each(std::execution::par, numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), [](int num)
    {
        std::cout << num;
    });
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: насколько я знаю, это рекоммендации для параллельного запуска, т.е. может и не параллельно for_each запуститься. Это так?

Comment: @влад, стандарт осторожно подходит к формулировкам обязательного. Политики — это указание того, чего Вы желаете. Как оно будет выполнено на самом деле — остаётся на откуп реализации.